# click on div with a changed class

Tags: jquery

```
$(".h1pass").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    var b = "page" + a;
    var c = $("#" + b);
    $(".page").hide();
    c.show();
    $('.h1act').removeClass('h1act').addClass('h1pass');
    $(this).removeClass('h1pass').addClass('h1act');
});
```

First click on `h1pass` works, but second click on the new `h1pass` (former `h1act`) doesn't work.

Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), in order to make it work, as :

```
$(document).on("click", ".h1pass", function() {
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    var b = "page" + a;
    var c = $("#" + b);
    $(".page").hide();
    c.show();
    $('.h1act').removeClass('h1act').addClass('h1pass');
    $(this).removeClass('h1pass').addClass('h1act');
});
```